# codes doesn't execute and gives InputQueue-JNI

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I use this code for storing text from EditText into SharedPreference!

LOG CAT: COLOR OF THIS IN LOG CAT IS GREEN:

```
09-14 10:38:38.659: I/InputQueue-JNI(7812): Sending finished signal for input channel '2c3d7020 ir.aiga.apps.quran/ir.aiga.apps.quran.SuraSurface (client)' since it is being unregistered while an input message is still in progress.
09-14 10:38:38.739: I/InputQueue-JNI(7812): Ignoring finish signal on channel that is no longer registered.
```

CODE:

```
iv_image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dialog_back);
            editors.putString(number+"text"+tempNumber, ettext.getText().toString());
            if(!ettext.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
            jalaliDate date=new jalaliDate();
            editors.putString(number+"text"+tempNumber+"time", date.getCurrentShamsidate());
            }else {
                editors.putString(number+"text"+tempNumber+"time", "");
            }

            editors.commit();
            cla.notifyDataSetChanged();
            ettext.setText("");
            dselect.dismiss();

            Log.d("DIMISSED", "");
```